# Get even / odd / all numbers between two numbers

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4, generate-series, set-returning-functions

I want to display all the numbers (even / odd / mixed) between two numbers (1-9; 2-10; 11-20) in one (or two) column.
Example initial data:

```
| rang  |              | r1 | r2 |
--------               -----|-----
| 1-9   |              | 1  | 9  |
| 2-10  |              | 2  | 10 |
| 11-20 |      or      | 11 | 20 |

CREATE TABLE initialtableone(rang TEXT);
INSERT INTO initialtableone(rang) VALUES
  ('1-9'),
  ('2-10'),
  ('11-20');

CREATE TABLE initialtabletwo(r1 NUMERIC, r2 NUMERIC);
INSERT INTO initialtabletwo(r1, r2) VALUES
  ('1', '9'),
  ('2', '10'),
  ('11', '20');
```

Result:

```
| output                         |
----------------------------------
| 1,3,5,7,9                      |
| 2,4,6,8,10                     |
| 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20  |
```

Comment: Can `rang` be empty or NULL? And is the result supposed to be an array or a string? Or would a set be better after all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
create table ranges (range varchar);

insert into ranges 
values
('1-9'),
('2-10'),
('11-20');

with bounds as (
  select row_number() over (order by range) as rn,
         range,
         (regexp_split_to_array(range,'-'))[1]::int as start_value,
         (regexp_split_to_array(range,'-'))[2]::int as end_value
  from ranges
)
select rn, range, string_agg(i::text, ',' order by i.ordinality)
from bounds b
  cross join lateral generate_series(b.start_value, b.end_value) with ordinality i
group by rn, range
```

This outputs:

```
rn | range | string_agg                   
---+-------+------------------------------
 3 | 2-10  | 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10           
 1 | 1-9   | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9            
 2 | 11-20 | 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! Possible for first and second rows generate only even and odd numbers?

Answer (score 2):

Building on your first example, simplified, but with PK:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl1 (
  tbl1_id serial PRIMARY KEY  -- optional
, rang text  -- can be NULL ?
);
```

Use [**`split_part()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) to extract lower and upper bound. (<strike>`regexp_split_to_array()`</strike> would be needlessly expensive and error-prone). And [**`generate_series()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html) to generate the numbers.

Use a [`LATERAL` join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803) and aggregate the set *immediately* to simplify aggregation. An [ARRAY constructor](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS) is fastest in this case:

```
SELECT t.tbl1_id, a.output  -- array; added id is optional
FROM  (
   SELECT tbl1_id
        , split_part(rang, '-', 1)::int AS a
        , split_part(rang, '-', 2)::int AS z
   FROM   tbl1
   ) t
 , LATERAL (
   SELECT ARRAY(  -- preserves rows with NULL
      SELECT g FROM generate_series(a, z, CASE WHEN (z-a)%2 = 0 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END) g
      ) AS output
   ) a;
```

AIUI, you want *every* number in the range *only* if upper and lower bound are a mix of even and odd numbers. Else, only return every 2nd number, resulting in even / odd numbers for those cases. This expression implements the calculation of the interval:

```
CASE WHEN (z-a)%2 = 0 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END
```

Result as desired:

```
output
-----------------------------
1,3,5,7,9
2,4,6,8,10
11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
```

You do *not* need [`WITH ORDINALITY`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450) in this case, because the order of elements is guaranteed.

The aggregate function [`array_agg()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html) makes the query slightly shorter (but slower) - or use [`string_agg()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html) to produce a string directly, depending on your desired output format:

```
SELECT a.output  -- string
FROM  (
   SELECT split_part(rang, '-', 1)::int AS a
        , split_part(rang, '-', 2)::int AS z
   FROM   tbl1
   ) t
, LATERAL (
      SELECT string_agg(g::text, ',') AS output
      FROM   generate_series(a, z, CASE WHEN (z-a)%2 = 0 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END) g
   ) a;
```

Note a **subtle difference** when using an aggregate function or `ARRAY` constructor in the `LATERAL` subquery: Normally, rows with `rang IS NULL`are excluded from the result because the `LATERAL` subquery returns **no row**.
If you aggregate the result immediately, "no row" is transformed to **one row** with a NULL value, so the original row is preserved. I added demos to the fiddle.

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/47d2dc/1)

You do not need a CTE for this, which would be more expensive.

Aside: The type conversion to `integer` removes leading / training white space automatically, so a string like this works as well for `rank`: `'  1  - 3'`.

Comment: Thanks this is helpfull ... wondering if there is any option of using range data types to create ranges with steps to create odd or even or mixed ranges something like range(lower-bound,upper-bound, step) with Built-in Range Types